# Multiplexed 7 segments using PIC16F877A using C

Tags: pic, mplab, multiplexing

this is only the second time i've asked a question on here. Last time was quite helpful so i thought i'd revisit since i'm stuck on another C project!

I'll just add that i'm more or less a total n00b at C but know almost enough to attempt this with minimal help (until now!) and i'm not asking for someone to do this for me, just for a few pointers (no pun intended) in the right direction.

I've done quite a bit of googling on this topic but i'm trying my best not to just copy and paste in code from some online source as i want to learn from this one so i'm trying to develop the code by myself.

What i'm trying to do then:
I've build myself a PIC development board with two common cathode 7 segment displays connected up to PORTD of the '877A. I've connected RB0 and RB1 to the transistors that switch on the 7 segs and have tested everything out with simple code and it works fine so the circuit has no issues at all. I've managed to create a program that counts from 0-9 which was very basic and i've decided now to try multiplexing and counting from 0-99. I've written some code and posted it below and i'd like to ask someone to kindly point out to me what i'm doing wrong with it. So far i've got the units digit counting 0-9 but the tens digit just seems to stay at 0.

I've a feeling i'm leaving out something but i dunno what. I'm probably also overcomplicating it a little.

I'm trying to work my way up to making a program that acts as a temperature sensor using the input of a thermistor potential divider circuit to the ADC of the PIC (which is my actual project) and displaying the value on a multiplexed display which isn't actually part of the project (we're only supposed to use one digit that alternates between '2' and '5' and 'C' for '25C' etc) but i want to take it a bit further so i'm trying to develop this for an improved version.

Anyway, that's enough of me rambling on i'll paste the code in and hopefully someone can help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <xc.h>

#pragma config CP = OFF, DEBUG = OFF, PWRTE = OFF
#pragma config CPD = OFF, LVP = OFF
#pragma config BOREN = OFF, WRT = OFF
#pragma config WDTE = OFF, FOSC = HS

#define _XTAL_FREQ 8000000

void segments (int digits);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    TRISD = 0x00;      //creates an output
    TRISB = 0x00;
    PORTD = 0x00;      //sends zeros to all bits of port D
    PORTB = 0x00;
    int i,j,num,tens,units,digits;
    do {
        for (i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            units=i%10;     //extract units digit
            num=i-units;    //takes units away leaving multiple of 10
            tens=num%10;    //extract tens digit
            for(j=0;j<20;j++)    //should display each ten and unit for 200ms
            {
                RB0=1;          //switch on units segment
                RB1=0;
                digits=units;
                segments(digits);
                __delay_ms (5);
                RB0=0;
                RB1=1;
                digits=tens;
                segments(digits);
                __delay_ms (5);
            }
        }
        }while (1);         //do while runs forever 
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void segments (int digits)
{
    switch (digits)
            {
                case 0:
                PORTD=0x3F;       //zero
                break;
                case 1:
                PORTD=0x06;       //one
                break;
                case 2:
                PORTD=0x5B;       //two
                break;
                case 3:
                PORTD=0x4F;       //three
                break;
                case 4:
                PORTD=0x66;       //four
                break;
                case 5:
                PORTD=0x6D;       //five
                break;
                case 6:
                PORTD=0x7D;       //six
                break;
                case 7:
                PORTD=0x07;       //seven
                break;
                case 8:
                PORTD=0x7F;       //eight
                break;
                case 9:
                PORTD=0x6F;       //nine
                break;
            }
}
```

If i've forgotten to add anything please do let me know. Thanks very much in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `tens = num / 10;` instead of `%`.

For example, if `i` is 52 while you calculate units `y`, extract the remaining from division by 10, wich is 2. Then you subtract 2 from 52 to get 50, and do the same in calculating tens, which will surely give you 0.